# After kombu upgrade getting <> is not JSON serializable for task_id

Tags: python, json, celery, kombu

I'm getting `ERROR EncodeError(TypeError('6JQAKHNMG9 is not JSON serializable',),)`after upgrade.

Successfully installed:

- amqp-2.1.4
- billiard-3.5.0.2
- celery-4.0.2
- kombu-4.0.2
- pytz-2017.2

(Initially required for Flower 0.9.1 installation)

Was running:

- amqp==1.4.9
- billiard==3.3.0.23
- celery==3.1.23
- kombu==3.0.35
- pytz==2016.10

Now I get:

```
05/10/2017 06:37:55.045 ERROR EncodeError(TypeError('6JQAKHNMG9 is not JSON serializable',),)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/src/gonzo/api/version1_0/application/api_main.py", line 191, in post
    retries=3)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 737, in send_task
    amqp.send_task_message(P, name, message, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/app/amqp.py", line 558, in send_task_message
    **properties
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 169, in publish
    compression, headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 252, in _prepare
    body) = dumps(body, serializer=serializer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 221, in dumps
    payload = encoder(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 35, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 54, in _reraise_errors
    reraise(wrapper, wrapper(exc), sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 50, in _reraise_errors
    yield
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 221, in dumps
    payload = encoder(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/utils/json.py", line 72, in dumps
    **dict(default_kwargs, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 251, in dumps
    sort_keys=sort_keys, **kw).encode(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 207, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 270, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/utils/json.py", line 62, in default
    return super(JSONEncoder, self).default(o)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 184, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
EncodeError: 6JQAKHNMG9 is not JSON serializable
```

My code:

Im passing a custom "task_id" which is a string, (not a JSON object) it used to work before the upgrade (If i revert versions it works again), what may be the correct format to pass a custom task_id?

```
celery.send_task('process_campaign',
                             exchange='gonzo',
                             queue='gold',
                             routing_key='gonzo.gold',
                             kwargs={'campaign_instance': campaign_instance},
                             task_id=campaign_instance.reference,
                             retries=3)
```

I tried:

```
task_id=json.dumps(campaign_instance.reference) or
task_id={'task_id': campaign_instance.reference}
```

Same error, any ideas, I can't find documentation for this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `version 4.0`, the default serializer in `celery` is `'json'`. Before the default was `'pickle'`. (I don't know the details for `kombu` package versions)

When sending the message you pass a `campaign_instance` argument which is probably not JSON serializable but is PICKLE serializable that's why it worked before.

You can change the default serializer in the settings specifying `'pickle'` which is the shortest way : http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#std:setting-task_serializer

Or you can modify your code to pass only JSON serializable arguments to your task.

Comment: [2017-05-13 00:22:03,916: CRITICAL/MainProcess] Can't decode message body: ContentDisallowed('Refusing to deserialize untrusted content of type pickle (application/x-python-serialize)',) [type:u'application/x-python-serialize' encoding:u'binary' headers:{}] After removing pickle I got a different error. Will move to Json format.